# see code when cross-posting page with Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net

When I use Server.Transfer the browser keeps the Previous Page on the URL bar. Also, when I try to view the source code of the page, shows the previous page code. I need to see the current page code. Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE8 the developer toolbar allows you to view the original and current DOM of the page.  In Firefox, you can use the Web Developer plugin to allow you to view the current page source.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Response.Redirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx) instead of Server.Transfer you have less of these problems though at the cost of having more round trips to your server.